# Show $f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_kx^k$ has a positive radius of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $ (a_k)_{k = 0}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Prove that

$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_kx^k$ has a positive radius of convergence.

Attempt: Suppose $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, then there is a $M > 0$ such that $|a_k| < M$ for all natural $k$. 
Then recall that $R = \frac{1}{\lim_{k → \infty} |a_k|^{1/k}}$ is the radius of convergence.

Thus, $R = \frac{1}{\lim_{k \to \infty} |a_k|^{1/k}} < \frac{1}{\lim_{k → \infty} M^{1/k}} = 1$ which is a positive number so the radius is positive.

Can anyone please help me? I don't know if this is a way to prove it. Any suggestions/help would be really appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically correct. Yet:

- You should replace the $\lim$ by $\limsup$.
- When passing to a limit a strict inequality can become an equality so the last $<$ is $\le$. Separately and more importantly, as pointed out by Jonas Meyer, you actually have $\ge$ as division "flips" the inequality.
- A sequence is not to be denoted by $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$, this is a series.  Instead denote it $(a_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$

Comment: Yes , I forgot to put the lim sup. Thank you.So $R = \frac{1}{lim sup_{k → \infty} |a_k|^{1/k}} \leq \frac{1}{lim sup_{k → \infty} M ^{1/k}} = 1$?

Comment: @Mahidevran: Your inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: why would it be $\geq$ instead of $\leq$?

Comment: @Mahidevran: If $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative numbers such that $a\leq b$, then $\dfrac1a\geq\dfrac1b$.  Also, a giveaway is that the conclusion is useless and often false, say if $a_k=0$ for all $k$.  You want $R>0$; you can show the stronger $R\geq 1$.